# How to execute a Javascript callback when a partial is rendered in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, partials

I've already created a custom class in JS that wraps Handlebars, this way I can execute a callback when a template has been rendered, but since partials in Handlebars are automatically generated, how could I execute a callback when a partial is rendered ?

I've tried to override the '>' helper but it doesn't work... and I have no idea how to do it otherwise.

Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: Probably you need to render partials manually. Overriding `Handlebars.VM.invokePartial` could also be the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlebars runtime calls method [`Handlebars.VM.invokePartial`](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/084e8fe1b77f4e9a327ce745aa7bb58c812e3510/lib/handlebars/runtime.js#L174) to exec the partial. You can override it for adding your callback function call:

```
Handlebars.VM.invokePartialOrigin = Handlebars.VM.invokePartial;
Handlebars.VM.invokePartial = function () {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
  Handlebars.VM.invokePartialOrigin.apply(Handlebars.VM, args);
  callback(args);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

More straightforward way:

```
const template = Handlebars.compile(source)
Handlebars.registerPartial(name, (ctx, options) => {
   callback(ctx)
   return template(ctx)
})
```